# Return the first occurrence of a user_id from a result set

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group, min

I have two tables (simplified to):

```
+----------------+
| attendances    |
+-----+----------+
| int | user_id  |
+-----+----------+
| int | event_id |
+-----+----------+

+-------------------------+
| events                  |
+------+------------------+
| int  | id               |
+------+------------------+
| date | performance_date |
+------+------------------+
```

And a simple query:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT user_id), events.performance_date
FROM attendances
INNER JOIN events
    ON event_id = events.id
GROUP BY performance_date
```

I only wish to count each `user_id` once, but the above query only removes the duplicates from each `performance_date` (allowing them to be duplicated across multiple dates).

Is there a query that can remove duplicate user_ids from the entire result set, and only include the first occurence (date wise)? I'm suspecting it might not be possible.

---

### Input/output examples:

If a user attended an event on 2010-10-10 and again on 2010-10-11, then the results would be:

```
1, 2010-10-10
```

Not:

```
1, 2010-10-10
1, 2010-10-11
```

Or:

```
2, 2010-10-10
```

If another user was added to the above, and they attended on 2010-10-10 and on 2010-10-12, then the results would be:

```
2, 2010-10-10
1, 2020-10-12
```

As I say, this may not be possible. The actual output isn't strictly important -- just so long as the unique number of people who attended a particular performance can be derived somehow.

**The data will be used to construct a cumulative graph of the growth in the number of unique users by event.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the earliest date per user, you can use aggregation:

```
select u.id user_id, min(e.date) first_event_date
from users u
inner join events e on u.event_id = e.id
group by u.id
```

Actually, you might be looking for histogram, that is the number of users per their earliest event date. You can do this by adding another level of aggregation:

```
select first_event_date, count(*) no_users
from (
    select min(e.date) first_event_date
    from users u
    inner join events e on u.event_id = e.id
    group by u.id
) t
group by first_event_date
```

Comment: @ChuckLeButt: doesn't the first query does that? It gives you one row per user, along with the date of its first event.

Comment: @ChuckLeButt, do you mean that you want to count the new users per event?

Comment: @ChuckLeButt . . . The second query appears to be exactly what you want.

Comment: I had implemented the second solution incorrectly. It does exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count all new users per event, you could use the following query:

```
SELECT Count(u.user_id), 
       e.performance_date 
FROM   attendances u 
       INNER JOIN `events` e 
               ON u.event_id = e.id 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT u1.user_id 
                  FROM   attendances u1 
                         INNER JOIN `events` e1 
                                 ON u1.event_id = e1.id 
                  WHERE  u1.user_id = u.user_id 
                         AND e1.performance_date < e.performance_date) 
GROUP  BY performance_date 
ORDER  BY performance_date
```

I tested it with the following set:

```
CREATE TABLE attendances 
  ( 
     user_id  INT, 
     event_id INT 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE `events` 
  ( 
     id               INT, 
     performance_date DATE 
  ); 

INSERT INTO attendances 
            (user_id, 
             event_id) 
VALUES      ( 1, 1),
            ( 1, 2),
            ( 2, 1),
            ( 2, 2),
            ( 3, 1),
            ( 4, 2);

INSERT INTO `events` 
            (id, 
             performance_date) 
VALUES      ( 1, '2020-07-24'), 
            ( 2, '2020-07-25');
```

And then the result is

```
3  2020-07-24
1  2020-07-25
```